# Scala recursion function that removes number from list needs work

Tags: scala, function, recursion

I have a recursive method in which remove it should all the zeroes from a given list.

```
def removeZ(list:List[Int], n:Int):List[Int] = list match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case h::t=>
    if (h == n)
      t
    else 
      h :: removeZ(t,n)
}
```

This removes one zero from the list but if the list has multiple zeros it won't. I tried adding another if else statement  that didn't work such as:

```
if else(t==n)
   removeZ(t,n)
```

How can I have all zeroes be removed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because after the first 0 you return the tail, you have to keep iterating:

```
scala> def removeZ(list: List[Int], n: Int): List[Int] = list match {
   |     case Nil => Nil
   |     case h :: t =>
   |       if (h == n)
   |         removeZ(t, n) // 0 found, skip it and iterate the tail
   |       else
   |         h :: removeZ(t, n)
   |   }
removeZ: (list: List[Int], n: Int)List[Int]

scala> removeZ(List(1,0,2,0,3), 0)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```